# Is it possible to access a HTML element using a ref in the data section of a component with Vue 2?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Is it possible to access `$refs` from the `data` section of a Vue (2.6.12) component e.g.

```
flickingPlugins: [new Arrow({
  prevElSelector: '.overview-arrow-prev',
  nextElSelector: '.overview-arrow-next',
  parentEl: this.$refs['overview-arrows'], // _this is undefined
})],
```

The reason I'm asking is because of the requirements of [the Flicking slider/carousel component](https://naver.github.io/egjs-flicking/). This component has an additional arrow plugin, for arrows to appear on either end to control sliding content left and right. The [plugin docs](https://naver.github.io/egjs-flicking/Plugins/#arrow) (3rd example) provide a Vue example that looks like this:

```
data() {
  return {
    plugins: [new Arrow({ parentEl: document.body })]
  }
}
```

The `parentEl` attribute is a way to specify where your custom arrow control elements will be located, and requires a HTMLElement value. I've always been told that element access should be done using refs, but how would you do that in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I'm aware and the [lifecycle documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#created) reads, this is not possible due to the design of Vue.js.

> #### Created
>
> [...] At this stage, the instance has finished processing the options which means **the following have been set up**: **data observation**, computed properties, [...]. However, the mounting phase has not been started, and **the `$el` property will not be available yet**.

So you will have to wait until your component has been mounted in order to access the element and its references.

Why not try an approach like this:

```js
{
  // ...
  data () {
    // no access to $el and $refs
    return {
      plugins: []
    }
  },

  mounted () {
    // here you have access to $el and $refs
    this.plugins.push(new Arrow({ parentEl: /* ... */ }))
  },
}
```